# DB2 shell run issue

Tags: shell, db2

When i run shell in DB2 instance.

```
VAR=`db2 CONNECT TO ${DBNAME} ${DBUSRSTR}`

if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  logErr ${MSG002E}
  logErr ${VAR}
  exit 2
fi
logInfo "【2】 DB2 connect " $?
logInfo ${VAR}


db2 set current schema TEST
if [ ! $? -eq 0 ]; then
  logErr ${MSG002E}
  exit 2
fi

2019-06-17 03:32:03,123 INFO [test.sh] 【2】 DB2 connect: 0
2019-06-17 03:32:03,124 INFO [test.sh] Database Connection Information Database server = DB2/LINUXX8664 10.5.5 SQL authorization ID = DB2INST1 Local database alias = TEST
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
2019-06-17 03:32:04,127 ERR [test.sh]
```

I don't know why it's seemed to connect success .. but can't execute sql?

I try it in the db2 command.

```
db2 =>
```

It was working fine. But in the shell. it's failed.

Comment: shell file is  under the /app/ directory .   I used the echo command .

Comment: [db2inst1@bcca3e296b2b /]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/bin:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/misc:/home/db2inst1/sqllib/db2tss/bin

Comment: Coding error. Db2-connections are *local* to the subshell in which they are made for most shells.  Easy workaround, perform the connect action inline, not in a subshell. This is a frequently asked question.

Comment: Can you give me a solution without change the code to fix it  ?   Bcz  the code is common , I just want to run it in my local..  Thank you again!!

Answer (score 1):

The result is expected. The [Db2 command line processor opens up a new front-end process](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010412.html) whenever it is invoked. Depending on how it is invoked, either the same or a different back-end process is used. If it is different, it would be a different connection.

Because you evaluate the call to Db2 in a subprocess of your shell script process, each time a different back-end process is involved. Hence, you would need a new database connection.

Try to open the connection as part of the shell process, not a subprocess. You need to redesign the flow.

Comment: Thank you for your great support !  I tried to find a way to solve via the link to the DB2 knowledge support. I do not want to change the code , Do i need change the DB2 env or any other ways to resolve this problem ?

Comment: You need to change your code. Execute the line to open the connection directly. Depending on whether it is sh / bash / ksh, there might be other tricks.